# Linq Transformations

Tags: linq

I have an example class such as:

```
class Foo 
{ 
    Int32 A; 
    IEnumerable<Int32> B; 
}
```

Is it possible to transform an enumerable of Foo to an enumerable of Int32, which would include the A and the contents of B  from all Foo's?

A non-LINQ solution would be:

```
var ints = new List<Int32>();
foreach (var foo in foos) {
    ints.Add(foo.A);
    ints.AddRange(foo.B);
}
```

The closest I could think of is:

```
var ints = foos.SelectMany(foo => var l = new List { foo.A }; l.AddRange(foo.B); return l);
```

But I wonder if there is a better solution that creating a temporary list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var results = foos.SelectMany(f => f.B.Concat(new[] { f.A}));
```

Basic approach is to create a new enumeration with one element by creating an array with one element which is `f.A`, concatenating this to the existing enumeration of `f.B` and finally flatten the sequence with `SelectMany()`

Comment: you don't need the `SelectMany` call, `Concat` already returns a single `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Femaref: the question asked for solving it for an Enumerable of `Foo`, not a single `Foo`

Answer (score 0):

as a `List<Int32>` per your non-Linq example

`var ints = Foo.B.ToList().Add(Foo.A);`

Lazy more Linq-ish solution

`var ints = Foo.B.Concat(new Int32[] {Foo.A})`

Comment: As a note: this will immediately evalulate the `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Femaref yes it will, but anything that get's him a list will as well.

Comment: I'm aware of that, however I think you should defer the evaluation until it is really needed, especially with LINQ.

Comment: @Femaref, for some reason I thought he said he wanted a `List<int32>`

Answer (score 0):

```
var ints = foos.SelectMany(f => f.B.Concat(new int[] { f.A}));
```

If you specifically need `f.A` **before** all elements from `f.B`:

```
var ints = foos.SelectMany(f => (new int[] { f.A }).concat(f.B));
```